# Help finding or making a white flag glyph

Tags: adobe-photoshop, icon, stock-images

I'm more of a programmer than designer so forgive me.  I am looking to sharpen my UX design skills though.

I found plenty of websites that give impressive sets of glyphs and icons, but I've been looking for one that has eluded me for days and it seems really simple. I need a simple white flag icon, but more than just 2 rectangles also. :)

Something like this but a little more refined:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5d/White_flag_icon.svg/250px-White_flag_icon.svg.png

Any ideas where I can find one or perhaps convert the above to something that would fit into a Glyph set like this (http://www.icondeposit.com/theicondeposit:24)?

Comment: Welcome to GD!  Even though you got an answer, I've closed this question as it doesn't really represent the sort of questions we encourage.  To be a viable question, it should address 1 specific need that can be answered objectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finding**: this should be the easiest part, there are so many free icons on the web. I found this free one on iconfinder in seconds:

[image]

**For converting**: the glyph set you linked has the PSD file included, so matching it should be easy by copying and applying the layer style.

[image]

So you should have everything you need, but for the future, if you need an icon to match the set you have perfectly, why not ask the designer of the iconset? I am sure he would be glad to help you for a small fee.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know about iconfinder, but it's amazing and is probably the best thing to come out of this question. I know there are many, but do you mind recommending 1 or 2 other similar resources that you use? Greatly appreciated.